# How to do a linear regression for each three rows in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, count, linear-regression

I want to make a linear regression for each three rows using for-loop and count, but I couldn't make it because I am confused with the input (x & y) for linear regression.

Here it is the code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

year=data_['Year']
value=data_['Value']
count=0
for a,b in zip(year,value):
    print(a,b) 
    count = count+1[input][1]
    window_type='rolling'

    if count%3 == 0 :
        x=data_.loc[0:3,['Year']]
        y=data_.loc[0:3,['Value']]

        reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
        x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.2 ,random_state=3)
        reg.fit(x,y)

        y4=4*reg.coef_ + reg.intercept_

        print("Equation : 4 *", reg.coef_, "+", reg.intercept_)
        print("Y4 : ", y4)
        print("====")
```

Actual result:

```
1 6.262008
2 5.795994
3 5.082562
Equation : 4 * [[-76.71615936]] + [209.89679764]
Y4 :  [[-96.96783982]]
====
1 285.433511
2 260.43560099999996
3 238.71312400000002
Equation : 4 * [[-76.71615936]] + [209.89679764]
Y4 :  [[-96.96783982]]
====
1 2.595145
2 2.508278
3 2.67997
Equation : 4 * [[-76.71615936]] + [209.89679764]
Y4 :  [[-96.96783982]]
====
```

The output I desire is:
every three rows result a different Y4

Please help me fixing this problem.

Comment: `x` and `y` don't seem to change in the loop. Therefore the result of the regression is always the same. Did you mean to use a and b to select from `data_`? It's difficult to test this however as in the code snippet `data_` is not defined.

Comment: @balleveryday yes, i want to change x and y , so the Y4's result always different for every three rows. data_ or the input is --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O-I4Lya9YovS-KW4JDvV9i2laMBeXSQT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think it would be easier if you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  in order to reproduce the issue without the use of external datasets.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can first consult the official document of ['sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit'](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit)
Make sure your input `reg.fit(X, y)` is of numpy.ndarray type. To be clear, in your case,

```
X = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(3,1)
y = np.array([6.262008, 5.795994, 5.082562])
reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X,y)
y4=4*reg.coef_ + reg.intercept_
print(np.squeeze(y4))
```

That should return,

> 4.534075333333335

Comment: that's not what i meant actually. i'm honestly looking for different y4 every three rows. so i could see the pattern in each three rows.